# How to edit message data before sending to DLT in Spring-Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I read a lot of documentation and a lot of issues on github of spring-kafka and still didn't get how to make spring DeadLetterRecovererFactory use my custom DeadLetterRecoverer.

Long story short - I want to modify the record before sending it do DLT.(But only before sending to DLT, not between retries).

In documentation of spring-kafka [DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer](http://devdoc.net/javaweb/spring/spring-kafka-docs-2.2.3/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.html) is said - "createProducerRecord(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord record, org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition topicPartition, org.apache.kafka.common.header.internals.RecordHeaders headers)
***Subclasses can override this method to customize the producer record to send to the DLQ.***"

So, here I'm creating my custom recoverer.
[image]

And injecting it into [DefaultErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters)
[image].

But this solution never works. The method createProducerRecord from MyDeadLetterRecoverer wasn't never called. Have no idea how to make this works.

But also later I found interesting [comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2265?sort=old#discussioncomment-2704503)

Did I missed something or is it Spring really don't allow DeadLetterRecoveryFactory to create an instances of subclasses? Why then they wrote this in their documentation?

Also I tried to implement ProducerInterceptor but this not exactly what I want because in this case I'm losing the spring retryable logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal, but you can do it...

1. Extend `DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory` and override `create()` to create the custom DLPR.
2. Extend `RetryTopicComponentFactory` and override `deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory()` to return the factory
3. Extend `RetryTopicConfigurationSupport` and override `createComponentFactory()` to return the component factory.

Unfortunately, you will need to copy much of the code in `super.create()` (and capture the field values passed in to the setters).

I opened an issue to make this easier: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2711

Comment: FYI https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2712/files - it will be available in the next release in a few weeks. If you want to try it, it is in 3.0.9-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: thank you for providing the info. It helped a lot!